# EACCES permission denied angular cli ng build in docker

Tags: angular, docker, angular-cli

I get a permissions error when I run

```
ng build --prod --env=prod
```

within a Docker container.  I think I'm taking care of all the various npm config settings, and the install is fine.  But when I run I get this error:

```
    EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/node/rbs/dist/0.0b84f6ea259174c0238a.chunk.js'
    Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/node/rbs/dist/0.0b84f6ea259174c0238a.chunk.js'
        at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:1061:18)
        at rimrafSync (/home/node/rbs/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js:254:15)
        at options.readdirSync.forEach.f (/home/node/rbs/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js:291:39)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at rmkidsSync (/home/node/rbs/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js:291:26)
        at rmdirSync (/home/node/rbs/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js:281:7)
        at Object.rimrafSync [as removeSync] (/home/node/rbs/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js:252:7)
        at Class.run (/home/node/rbs/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/build.js:29:16)
        at Class.run (/home/node/rbs/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:250:40)
        at resolve (/home/node/rbs/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:261:20)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Class.validateAndRun (/home/node/rbs/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:240:12)
        at Promise.resolve.then.then (/home/node/rbs/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:140:24)
        at <anonymous>
```

Here is my docker config:

```
    FROM node:8.11.3-alpine as build

    RUN apk add --update python make

    ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
    ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
    USER node

    RUN mkdir /home/node/rbs && \
          npm install -g -f @angular/cli@1.7.4

    ##
    ##  The section below is split to save cache time

    #
    # dependencies build only (only includes files for npm install)
    #
    RUN npm -g config set user root

    ADD ./package.json /home/node/rbs
    ADD ./package-lock.json /home/node/rbs

    RUN cd /home/node/rbs && \
          npm install

    #
    # Source build with ng (requires all sources)
    #
    ADD . /home/node/rbs

    RUN cd /home/node/rbs && \
          ng build --prod --env=prod


    #
    #  Runtime; we will vend resources via nginx
    #
    FROM nginx:1.13.8-alpine

    COPY --from=build /home/node/rbs/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

    ADD ./container-files .
```

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file?  Is the `Dockerfile` in your project's root directory, alongside the `package.json` file and what not?  Does your working tree happen to have a `dist` directory already?

Comment: Yes! I had a dist directory left over from a previous local run.  If you add as an answer I'll award

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`docker build` by default will take the entire current directory as its "context" directory, and then when your Dockerfile says `ADD . /home/node/rbs`, that directory gets added to the image.  However, if your working tree already has a `dist` directory, that gets copied in too, and the `ng build` command has to contend with the pre-existing content.

You can verify whether or not this is the problem by running

```
rm -rf dist
docker build .
```

A more permanent fix is to create a [.dockerignore file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) that tells Docker to not include the `dist` directory when it does the build.

```
echo /dist >> .dockerignore
docker build .
```

If the `dist` directory already exists, the `ADD` command will add it [owned by root](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add):

> All new files and directories are created with a UID and GID of 0, unless the optional --chown flag specifies [something else] ....

Since you've told `ng build` to run as an alternate `NODE` user it won't be able to delete the root-owned `dist` tree, which leads to the error you see.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer here!